# How to find how much reputation I gained since a particular date?

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-graph, dates

In retrospection I would love to see how much reputation I gained from certain period onwards. I can look at my reputation tab in my profile to see the recent reps gained but how do I see how much I gained from say, last october 26? I can try the graphical view

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/661933/nawfal?tab=reputation&sort=graph&StartDate=2013-02-22%2022:07:13Z
```

But it only gives a visual perspective, not a hard data. Can I get a **cumulative figure of rep** gained from date xxxx to date yyyy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how much I gained from say, last october 26?

Using your [network profile reputation graph](https://stackexchange.com/users/335069/nawfal?tab=reputation)

4900(current score) - 2471 = 2429

[image]